# disabling gradle war transitive dependencies stops jstl from being added to the final war

Tags: gradle, jstl, war, transient

I'm using Gradle 4.8.

The following example creates a war file, when "gradle buildWar" is run.
While myWarLibs.transitive is set to "true", both jstl and common-lang libraries are getting added to the resulting war file.

However, when I change myWarLibs.transitive to "false", jstl library stops being added. The behaviour remains the same even if jstl is the only library to add.

Could somebody explain me why setting transitive to false stops jstl from being added when jstl is an import?

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
  myWarLibs {
    transitive = false 
  }
}

task buildWar (type: War) {
  archiveName = 'result.war'
  classpath configurations.myWarLibs
}

dependencies {
  myWarLibs 'jstl:jstl:1.0.6'
  myWarLibs group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `javax.servlet:jstl:1.0.6`? It's basically the same artifact. If you look into `jstl:jstl:1.0.6`'s POM you'll see that they moved. Maybe this relocation is the reason?

Comment: Fixing dependency to myWarLibs 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.0.6' fixed the issue.